# What is the difference between $\{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\}^*$?

Tags: computer-science, automata

I am trying to understand the difference between the alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$ and 
$\Sigma = \{0,1\}^*$ For $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$. I searched online and found that it can be {$\epsilon$, 0,1,00,01,10,11,...}
and another search that its only stirings of length two {00,11,10,01} but for $\Sigma = \{0,1\}^*$ only thing I got was that its all possible combinations of 0 and 1. it seems to me like {0,1} and $\{0,1\}^*$ are equal because any string you can make with one can be made with the other. How are they different?

Comment: $\{0,1\}^*$ isn't an alphabet, it's the set of all words you can write with the alphabet $\{0,1\}$. What search told you about strings of length $2$?

Comment: The simplest difference between $\{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\}^*$ is that the former has exactly two elements (namely $0$ and $1$) whereas the latter has infinitely many elements (namely $\epsilon,0,1,00,01,10,11,000,\dots$).

Comment: I think what @objectAi is meaning to ask is, "what is the difference between $\{0,1\}^*$ and $(\{0,1\}^*)^*$"? The answer, of course, is that they are the same; Kleene closure is an idempotent operator.